# Azure Mobile APP with Easy Table and Easy APIs gives error "Unsupported Service"

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

I have created mobile app and wanted to use Easy Table and Easy APIs. However whenever I go to that location it shows "Unsupported Service".

Below is the image link of my azure account console.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If my answer below helped, don't hesitate to validate it. :-)

Answer (score 11):

Easy Tables and Easy APIs are (currently) only supported for Node (Mobile Apps or Migrated Mobile Service) applications, not for .NET applications.

Please see the following thread for more details https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/en-US/07ee8c8a-a2fc-47ad-aca4-2ec4b5e8ac4a/enabling-mobile-extension-for-your-app-runs-forever?forum=azuremobile

Comment: Adding on to what @Benjamin said,  not only does it require Node.js, but it also requires that the Node.js app has certain artifacts in the app.  For instance, the tables must be located in the tables directory and have a .json file for handling settings.   Migrated mobile services have these artifacts already, as do tables created with the Easy Tables.  if you wish to use Easy Tables / Easy APIs, the recommendation is to install the quick start (which you can do from the Azure Portal) and start from that point.

Comment: I am facing the same problem.
I took the quickstart code and installed it in bitbucket. Also, I setup a continuous  deployment from bitbucket master branch. After pushing I am facing above issue. 
All the folders in node.js are appropriate as I downloaded them instead of creating from scratch. 
Any idea whats the issue?

Comment: Aside from .NET, Easy Tables maintains the tables for you.  That means you cannot link it to BitBucket, Github or some other source code control system and use continuous deployment.  You never get the changes back to your source code control system.  Easy Tables is for those who require a completely portal driven experience with no DevOps type features.

Comment: That means we are able to create table only by publishing our app, does it?  is there any good article explains the difference between node.js and .net?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Easy Tables with a .Net backend.  I ran into the same problem following the Quick Start steps posted by Microsoft.  What you want to do is delete your application in the portal, create a new one, setup the database, then click Easy tables.  It will initialize for you using the database you created.

Do not click on any Quick Start links.